# How search by all fields in ElasticSearch 6.2?

Tags: elasticsearch

I send the request:

```
POST http://localhost:9200/mydatabase/users/_search
```

with body:

```
{
    "query": {
        "fuzzy" : {
            "role" : {
                "value": "admn",
                "boost": 1.0,
                "fuzziness": 1,
                "prefix_length": 0,
                "max_expansions": 100
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I get this responsse:

```
 "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "mydatabase",
                "_type": "users",
                "_id": "mKstz2IBuOClWUbC0-1v",
                "_score": 0.5198604,
                "_source": {
                    "user": "Сорокин Роман",
                    "description": "Данному пользователю предоствлена админка",
                    "role": "Admin"
                }
            }
        ]
```

How to write a query if I want get search by all fields, not only field "role" and use fuzzy?

Сan I write a query without configuring the mapping?

Comment: You have a mix of two languages in your documents? How do you plan to analyze the fields

Comment: @sramalingam24  I going use language analyzers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you mention "without configuring mapping" - I assume you already considered [_all field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-all-field.html#CO236-1) ( which requires change in mapping ).

Options are:

1 - Use ["Query String" query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html) with out default_field and use [Lucene Query syntax](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_4_1/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/package-summary.html) for fuzzy match ; As mentioned in documentation - by default it combines all fields to generate the query .

```
GET /_search
{
    "query": {
        "query_string" : {
           query" : "admn~"
        }
    }
}
```

You can also target specific fields (including wildcard).

```
 GET /_search
    {
        "query": {
            "query_string" : {
               "fields": "role*" 
               "query" : "admn~"
            }
        }
    }
```

2-  To use [bool query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) and should clause to combine multiple fields.

```
POST _search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "fuzzy": {
            "role": {
              "value": "admn",
              "boost": 1,
              "fuzziness": 1,
              "prefix_length": 0,
              "max_expansions": 100
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "fuzzy": {
            "role2": {
              "value": "admn",
              "boost": 1,
              "fuzziness": 1,
              "prefix_length": 0,
              "max_expansions": 100
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```